# eBay API SOAP call to GetOrders fails with 'Validation of the authentication token in API request failed'

Tags: soap, ebay-api

I encounter an issue where I invoke eBay `GetOrders` API

```
<faultstring>Auth token is invalid.</faultstring>
    <faultactor>http://www.ebay.com/ws/websvc/eBayAPI</faultactor>
    <detail>
        <FaultDetail>
            <ErrorCode>931</ErrorCode>
            <Severity>Error</Severity>
            <DetailedMessage>Validation of the authentication token in API request failed.</DetailedMessage>
```

I am able to successfully get a token from eBay and refresh it, I tested the rest API with the same token and it seems to be working properly.

Any ideas how this can be resolved? or what can cause this error? eBay docs provide some hints about the token validity but this was tested and it does not seems to be the issue.

All is written using Java SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. There are two ways to authenticate to ebay API, one is using oauth and the other is Auth n Auth. it appears that when you like to use the java soap api you need to get a token via auth n auth method and ask for a session id, once that you have the session id you need to ask for a token. the oauth method is suited for the REST API.

I hope that will help someone

Comment: You can also use oauth via ebay's XML API, but not their SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

Did You tried to test token by the [ebay developer](https://go.developer.ebay.com/) testing tool? There is a tool where You can test tokens, headers, requests etc.

PS. Make sure that You choose right enviroment - sandbox or production. Token for the sandbox is different as token for production environment.